# Can not run fsm in Erlang

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, fsm

Hello i am trying to run a `fsm` using `gen_statem` in a separate process from the caller.I am also trying to keep in its state arguments the caller, so it can be updated after each state change.
I keep getting this error :

```
  ** State machine <0.123.0> terminating
** Last event = {internal,init_state}
** When server state  = {sitting_home,{state,"None",0,0,[<0.116.0>]}}
** Reason for termination = error:{'function not exported',
                                      {fsm,callback_mode,0}}
** Callback mode = undefined
** Stacktrace =
**  [{gen_statem,call_callback_mode,1,[{file,"gen_statem.erl"},{line,1610}]},
     {gen_statem,enter,7,[{file,"gen_statem.erl"},{line,679}]},
     {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]

=CRASH REPORT==== 12-Dec-2019::00:14:42.717000 ===
  crasher:
    initial call: fsm:init/1
    pid: <0.123.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception error: undefined function fsm:callback_mode/0
      in function  gen_statem:call_callback_mode/1 (gen_statem.erl, line 1610)
      in call from gen_statem:enter/7 (gen_statem.erl, line 679)
    ancestors: [<0.116.0>]
    message_queue_len: 0
    messages: []
    links: []
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: false
    status: running
    heap_size: 1598
    stack_size: 27
    reductions: 5805
  neighbours:
```

I have looked in the erlang documentation and i can see no callback `mode` that needs to be implemented [here](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_statem.html#start-3).

**Module**

```
-module(fsm).
-record(state,{
    current="None",
    intvCount=0,
    jobCount=0,
    monitor
}).
-export([init/1,start/0]).
-export([hire/2,fire/1,interview/2]).

-behaviour(gen_statem).


start()->
    gen_statem:start(?MODULE,[self()],[]).

init(Monitor)->
    {ok,sitting_home,#state{current="None",jobCount=0,intvCount=0,monitor=Monitor}}.

sitting_home({intv,Company},State=#state{intvCount=C,monitor=M})->
     gen_statem:reply(M,"Got an interview from:"++Company++" going interviewing"),
     {next_state,interviewing,State#state{intvCount=C+1}};
sitting_home(Event,State)->
     gen_statem:reply(State#state.monitor,{unexpected , Event}),
     {next_state,sitting_home,State}.

interviewing({rejected,Company},State)->
    gen_statem:reply("Booh got rejected by :"++ Company),
    {next_state,sitting_home,State};
interviewing({accepted,Company},State=#state{jobCount=J})->
    gen_statem:reply("Hooray got accepted"),
    {next_state,working,State#state{jobCount=J+1,current=Company}};
interviewing(_,State)->
    gen_statem:reply("Unknown message"),
    {next_state,interviewing,State}.


working(fire,State=#state{current=C})->
    gen_statem:reply("Unexpected event"),
    {next_state,working,State#state{current="None"}};
working(Event,State)->
        gen_statem:reply("Unexpected event"),
        {next_state,working,State}.
```

**Events**

```
hire(Company,PID)->
    gen_statem:sync_send_event(PID,{hire,self(),Company},0).
fire(PID)->
    gen_statem:sync_send_event(PID,{fire,self()},0).
interview(Company,PID)->
    gen_state:sync_send_event(PID,{intv,Company},0).
```

**P.S** I use `gen_statem` because the shell told me the `gen_fsm` is deprecated.I do not know the equivalent for `sync_send_event`.Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `Module:callback_mode` [is documented](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_statem.html#Module:callback_mode-0) at the page you linked. When you have a function for each state (`sitting_home`, `interviewing`, etc.) it should be

   ```
   callback_mode() -> state_functions.
   ```
2. The state functions take *3* arguments, not 2. You are missing the first one, [`EventType`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_statem.html#type-event_type) which should be `{call, From}` in your case.
3. The equivalent for `sync_send_event` can just be `call`, but then your state functions should always reply.
4. You can combine `reply` and `next_state` in the return value of a callback, e.g.

   ```
   working(Event,State)->
       gen_statem:reply("Unexpected event"),
       {next_state,working,State}.
   ```

   can become

   ```
   working({call, From}, Event, State)->
       {next_state, working, State, {reply, From, "Unexpected event"}}.
   ```

   Even if you don't do this, `reply` [needs a `From` argument](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_statem.html#reply-1):

   ```
   working({call, From}, Event, State)->
       gen_statem:reply(From, "Unexpected event"),
       {next_state,working,State}.
   ```

Comment: Ok so using gen_statem all my states must have 3 args and one of them is `{Call/cast,From}`.If this is the case i still don't get the `{reply,From,Message}` argument in the return. Does this issue a `gen_statem:reply` that does the reply and returns the state ?

Comment: 1. "one of them is {Call/cast,From}" `{call, From}`/`cast`/`timeout`/etc. But not `{cast,From}`. 2. Yes, you can have an action or a list of actions as the 4th component of the tuple. Not just replies, but other actions are allowed. See http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_statem.html#type-event_handler_result.

Comment: But i do not get the syntax when calling `reply` :  `{ function name, argument} ` resulting in a call to that method.Is it something specific to `gen_statem` a convention or it is erlang specific ?

Comment: It's specific to `gen_statem`. And `{reply, From, "Unexpected event"}` here is an action (http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_statem.html#type-action) and only coincides with the function name.